Coordinates, components, and change of basis
New to Math Stack Exchange, and struggling a bit to properly pose the question, but here goes:
I have some confusion about coordinates, components, basis, and change of basis. I understand the mechanics of how to do this, and crank through the calculation, but it is the concept of what is actually going on which is confusing me.
Let's take an example where I have a vector and a chart in $(x,y)$. Here we have the standard basis $\mathbf{e}_x = (1,0)$ and $\mathbf{e}_y = (0,1)$. I know these are column vectors, but to simplify things, I will write them as rows. Let's suppose we have a super simple example of a vector $V = 2 \mathbf{e}_x = 2 (1,0)$. So in this case the basis vectors I would regard as having a length of $1$ and the vector component $2$.
Now suppose I have a different chart $(\bar{x},\bar{y})$ with basis vectors $\bar{\mathbf{e}}_x$ and  $\bar{\mathbf{e}}_y$  physically twice as long as the standard basis. The same vector $V$ in the new chart would be $V = 1 \bar{\mathbf{e}}_x$. That makes sense to me; the basis vector gets physically longer by a factor of $2$, and the component decreases by half (covariant/contravariant). Now, here is where I get confused. If I am in $(\bar{x},\bar{y})$, then I still measure the basis as one unit, ie  $V = 1 \bar{\mathbf{e}}_x = 1 (1,0)$ since I might not have any knowledge of $(x,y)$ so the basis vector to me in $(\bar{x},\bar{y})$ is still a unit vector with length one, and vector with component $1$, correct?
The transition maps would be $x = 2 \bar{x}$ and $\bar{x} = x/2$ with ${\partial x}{/\partial \bar{x}}=2$ and  ${\partial \bar{x}}/{\partial x} = 1/2$.
Considering points $P(x,y)=(x,y)$ and $\bar{P}(\bar{x},\bar{y})=(\bar{x},\bar{y})$ then the basis vectors would be
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\partial P(x,y)}{\partial x} = \dfrac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial x} = (1,0) = \mathbf{e}_x
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\partial \bar{P}(\bar{x}, \bar{y})}{\partial \bar{x}} = \dfrac{\partial (\bar{x},\bar{y})}{\partial  \bar{x}} = (1,0) = \bar{\mathbf{e}}_x 
\end{equation}
Seems ok to me so far. Now using the chain rule
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&V = 2 \mathbf{e}_x = 2 \dfrac{\partial P(x,y)}{\partial x}  \\
\\
&= 2 \dfrac{\partial \bar{x}}{\partial x} \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial \bar{x}}  \dfrac{\partial P(x,y)}{\partial x} \\
\\
&= 2\bigg( \dfrac{1}{2}\bigg) \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial \bar{x}}  \dfrac{\partial P(x,y)}{\partial x} = 1 \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial \bar{x}}  \dfrac{\partial P(x,y)}{\partial x} 
\end{split}
\end{equation}
So we can interpret
\begin{equation}
V= 1 \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial \bar{x}}  \dfrac{\partial P(x,y)}{\partial x} = (1)(2) \mathbf{e}_x
\end{equation}
as a vector with a component of $1$ and a basis vector twice that of the standard basis vector with component $2$ which ok kind of makes sense. But my confusion arises when I consider
\begin{equation}
V= 1 \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial \bar{x}}  \dfrac{\partial P(x,y)}{\partial x} = 1  \dfrac{\partial P(x,y)}{\partial \bar{x}}
 \end{equation}
Ok so now we think about a component of $1$, but with a basis that describes how points in $(x,y)$ change with $\bar{x}$ which seems confusing how that works.
Furthermore,
\begin{equation}
 V= 1  \dfrac{\partial P(x,y)}{\partial \bar{x}} =  1  \dfrac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial \bar{x}} = 1  \dfrac{\partial (2\bar{x},2\bar{y})}{\partial \bar{x}} = (1)(2) \bar{\mathbf{e}}_x
 \end{equation}
but we know from above that $V = 1 \bar{\mathbf{e}}_x$, so that is another place where I am confused. Appreciate any insight.

Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Did you mean $\mathbf{e}_y = (0,1);?$

Since you rightfully mentioned the chain rule I demonstrate (again) in detail
how straightforward it is to derive everything about an arbitrary coordinate transformations
from that.
The coordinate transformation is
\begin{align}
(x,y)\mapsto (\bar x,\bar y)=(\tfrac 12x,y)\,.
\end{align}
Its Jacobian $J$ and the inverse of that are
\begin{align}
J&=\pmatrix{\frac12&0\\0&1}\,,&J^{-1}&=\pmatrix{2&0\\0&1}\,.
\end{align}
To make the proof below automatic one should write the coordinate basis
vectors as partial derivatives (which is common in modern DG):
\begin{align}
\mathbf{e}_x&={1\choose 0}=\partial_x\,,&\mathbf{e}_y&={0\choose 1}=\partial_y\,,&
\bar{\mathbf{e}}_x&={2\choose 0}=\partial_\bar x\,,& \bar{\mathbf{e}}_y&={0\choose 1}=\partial_\bar y 
\end{align}
Then the chain rule applied to $f=f(\bar x,\bar y)$
yields the transformation law
\begin{align}
\pmatrix{\partial_x \\\partial_y}=J\pmatrix{\partial_\bar x \\ \partial_ \bar y}
\end{align}
for basis vectors.
Proof.

\begin{align}\partial_x f(\bar x,\bar y)&=\partial_\bar x f(\bar x,\bar y)\,\partial_x\bar x+\partial_\bar y f(\bar x,\bar y)\,\partial_x\bar y=\partial_\bar xf(\bar x,\bar y)\tfrac12\,,\\[2mm]\partial_y f(\bar x,\bar y)&=\partial_\bar x f(\bar x,\bar y)\,\partial_y\bar x+\partial_\bar y f(\bar x,\bar y)\,\partial_y\bar y=\partial_\bar yf(\bar x,\bar y)\,.\end{align}

Clearly,
\begin{align}
\pmatrix{\partial_\bar x \\\partial_\bar y}&=J^{-1}\pmatrix{\partial_x \\ \partial_ y}\,.
\end{align}
This is the covariant transformation law for the basis vectors from the
$(x,y)$-coordinates to $(\bar x,\bar y)\,.$
A general vector $\mathbf{v}$ should not depend on the representation in a basis:
\begin{align}
\mathbf{v}=v^x\partial_x+v^y\partial_y=v^\bar x\partial_\bar x+v^\bar x\partial_\bar y\,.
\end{align}
Inserting $I=JJ^{-1}$ into this formal scalar product where the
tuples $(v^x,v^x)\,,(v^\bar x,v^\bar x)$
of the components of $\mathbf{v}$ are column vectors yields the
(contravariant) transformation law
\begin{align}
(v^\bar x,v^\bar y)=(v^x,v^y)\,J=(v^x,v^y)\pmatrix{\frac 12&0\\0&1}\,.
\end{align}
In short:
\begin{align}
v^\bar x&=\tfrac 12v^x\,,&v^\bar y&=v^y\,,&\partial_\bar x&=2\partial_x\,,&\partial_\bar y&=\partial_y\,.
\end{align}
as expected.

Having read and I think mostly followed your thoughts here, I believe that what's happened is this: your confusion begins quite a bit earlier than you may actually realize. You have accepted as true some statements that actually are not true and in fact are barely even false because they unfortunately don't make grammatical sense to begin with. To my eye, things begin to go wrong in the line where you say "Consider points..." followed by some kind of derivative calculations. From this point onwards, I believe your calculations only seem to you like they make a bit of sense because you're using symbols in a way that might be (almost) correct if the mathematical context itself were correct. But I'm afraid that the mathematical context (or the "grammar", if you like) has become separated from the symbols in the line I quoted above. I should say - the symbols we use in calculus are, in my opinion, often very confusing because many of them have multiple mathematical meanings. Particularly variables like $x$ and $y$ - sometimes we're supposed to treat variables/coordinates like (stand-ins for) actual numbers, and sometimes we're supposed to treat them as functions in their own right.
To fix things, I would suggest going back to that line I quoted and thinking about what you mean mathematically by differentiating $P(x,y)$ with respect to $x$. You called $P(x,y)$ a point - a fixed point does not vary with respect to anything, so any kind of derivative of it would be 0. Now this could be rectified by saying "actually, $P(x,y) = (x,y)$ is the identity mapping from the plane to itself and the output of a mapping can vary if the input varies". However, I doubt that you really want to differentiate the identity map because it's not a very interesting map. But ok, let's say you do that. Then you next calculate that this derivative is equal to the vector $\mathbf{e}_x$ - what does it mean to you mathematically that a derivative would be equal to a vector? There are contexts where this can make sense, but those are somewhat more advanced contexts than I think you are trying to deal with. Usually a derivative at this level is some kind of number (or function that outputs numbers). At best here, it is a (row-)matrix that you might think of as more-or-less the same as a vector, but even that would be of a very different sort.
I don't think it would be valuable for me to go through the remaining calculations in this way, but I hope this helps a bit to at least see where the problem may have begun. I was going to finally speculate on what your overall goal was and try to suggest how to achieve it in a more correct way, but I see that Kurt G has now done exactly this in his great answer -- if you can understand his notation, then he has now put things on a correct footing that you should try to make sense of for yourself.

Thanks for the comments, and to again take this very simply, suppose we take your example of the transition $(\bar{x},\bar{y})$ = (x/2,y) so that $\partial \bar{x}/ \partial x = 1/2$, $\partial  x / \partial \bar{x}=2$,  $\partial \bar{y}/ \partial y = \partial  y / \partial \bar{y} = 1$. And we use the definition that $\mathbf{e}_x = (1,0) = \partial / \partial x$ and $\mathbf{e}_y = (0,1) = \partial / \partial y$. (Again assuming really column vectors).
Suppose we have a vector with components $2$ and $0$
$$
V= v^{x} \dfrac{\partial}{ \partial x} + v^{y} \dfrac{\partial} {\partial y } = 2 \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}
$$
Now to use the chain rule
$$
 \begin{split}
&V=  2 \dfrac{\partial }{\partial x } =  2 \dfrac{\partial \bar{x}}{\partial x}   \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial \bar{x} } \dfrac{\partial }{\partial x } \\
& = 2 \bigg(\dfrac{1}{2} \bigg)  \dfrac{\partial }{\partial\bar{ x }} = 1 \dfrac{\partial }{\partial\bar{ x }} 
\end{split}
$$
which is what we want. Correct?

Correct. $\phantom.$
